# Document with multiple versions

Tags: exam, versions

I would like to deal with two different versions of an exam, namely vA and vB. These two versions would differ by content and but also by title, as you can see from the example I included here below.
I found many posts on the subject, but I'm still confused on which is the most suitable solution for my case.

Let me know what you think!

Best regards and thanks in advance for your cooperation!

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,addpoints]{exam}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}


\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\newcommand{\examnum}{TE n\textsuperscript{o}2 (s\'erie A)}


\begin{document}
    
\title{\examnum}
\author{Enseignant: Pinco Pallino}
\date{\examdate}
\maketitle

\clearpage
\begin{questions}
    \question 
    \input{exercices/factorisations_va.tex}
    \vspace{2cm}
    
    \question 
    \input{exercices/factorisations_vb.tex}
    \vspace{2cm}
\end{questions}


\end{document}
```

Comment: When I had to do this, I used the 'other' `exam.cls` i.e. the one on CTAN which is not in TeX Live because its name (obviously) conflicts with `exam.cls`. I think I used this one: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exams.

Comment: "which is the most suitable solution" is very opinion based. "for my case" is even harder to answer, because we do not really know your case, but only some aspects of your case. However, a slight reformulation could be a useful question, namely the question of what the advantages and disadvantages of the various solutions are. Which solution do you prefer so far and why?  Or which packages/classes have you shortlisted so far and why?

Comment: BTW: Do you want to select the different questions yourself? I'm asking, because in this case, maybe even using two documents would be a suggestion. Do you want to have questions where, for example, only some values/numbers are changed? Do you want multiple choice questions which are the same but with random order of answers? These are only some aspects, that can be relevant for "the most suitable solution".

Comment: BTW: For an overview of packages and classes for exams see [the CTAN Catalogue](https://www.ctan.org/topic/exam). Maybe the `exam` extension [`examz`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/examz) would be a suggestion, because the “document class facilitates the writing of questions with random elements, the creation of multiple versions of an exam, and the use of separate files as question banks.”

Comment: But maybe you are just searching for a package for [conditional typesetting](https://ctan.org/topic/cond-comp) like [`optional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/optional) or [`comment`](https://ctan.org/pkg/comment).

Comment: I used to use C++ code to generate LaTeX code (see http://www.elfsoft2000.com/worksheets/index.htm),  I could show you how if you are interested.

Comment: Maybe you should add to your question alternatives you found, AND make more evident, what is puzzling or confusing you. // In the end, may be creating and trying some test cases, which reflect your project, is the way to go: then you'll see benefits, shortcomings, complications etc.